# How to specify different size for each grid element and maintain wrapping?

Tags: css, css-grid

### Problem:

Right now both of the grid elements below are  `min: 250px, max: 1fr` in size. They wrap on screen size `<250px`

I'm trying to achieve the following:

- the first element to be `min: 250px, max: 2fr`
- the second element to be  `min: 250px, max: 1fr`

but also maintain wrapping to `1fr` each on screen size `<250px` (the way they wrap now basically)

### Code:

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dEBQgm?editors=1100

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child">Child 2</div>
</div>

...

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 16px;
}

.child {
  background: #aaa;
  height: 32px
}
```

I tried this but I lost the wrapping:

```
grid-template-columns: minmax(250px, 2fr) minmax(250px, 1fr);
```

Comment: Basically **you can't** - *that's not a repeating grid really*. I'm not really clear on what effect you are after.

Comment: This sounds a flexbox job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try flexbox for this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin:-8px; /*Pay attention to this! You may need overflow:hidden on a parent container*/
}

.child {
  background: #aaa;
  height: 32px;
  min-width: 250px;
  flex-basis: 0%;
  margin: 8px;
}

.container> :first-child {
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.container> :last-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.container-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(250px, 2fr) minmax(250px, 1fr);
  grid-gap:16px;
}
.container-grid > .child {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
flexbox with wrapping
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child">Child 2</div>
</div>
grid without wrapping:
<div class="container-grid">
  <div class="child">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child">Child 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's unfortunate that you loose the `gap` functionality though.

Comment: @Un1 yes we need to hack this with some margin

Comment: @Un1 I edited the answer to make it close the gap more accurate